# In a asp:repeater,I use asp:checkbox,but the OnCheckedChanged doesn't fire

Tags: asp.net

Here is the code:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater1" OnItemCommand="checkChange">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Table runat="server" Width="80%">
            <asp:TableRow runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="80%">
                <asp:TableCell Width="80%" HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="删除" Visible="<%#administrator %>" />
                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkBox" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"IID")%>' AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="checkChange" EnableViewState="false"/>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"invText") %>'></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

and the function is:

```
 protected void checkChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("it works well!");
    }
```

but when I click the checkbox,nothing happen...Thank you ...

Comment: Why you have disabled view state for checkbox ??

Answer (score 1):

Because you have provided single `event handler` to both the `CheckBox` and the `Repeater`.

But of course because both `OnItemCommand` and `OnCheckedChanged` events has same delegate signatures i.e `void target(object sender, EventArgs e)` so it won't raise any kind of error.

**Code working fine like this :**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" Width="80%">
                    <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="80%">
                        <asp:TableCell Width="80%" HorizontalAlign="Left">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkBox" Text="Click me if u dare." AutoPostBack="true"
                                OnCheckedChanged="checkChange" EnableViewState="false" />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

**Back end**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Name no.: " + i.ToString() });
            repeater1.DataSource = dt;
            repeater1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void checkChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Clicked called at :" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss"));
    }
```

Comment: But which one should I provide this event handler to?I have tried both,but still can't work.

Comment: I am sure that this code isn't generating any error, I have tested it and its all right, you should see the problem from different angles there should be something else in your full source code with is causing this issue, Try to use breakpoints & debug your code. Use other elements like provide a click event to your button in repeater there and see if that click event fires or not.

Comment: A click event to the button in there can fire well...I use the same function 'checkChange',but the checkbox still can not work...What do you mean that "you have tested it"?The page show "it works well"?

Comment: I copied your code & tested it on my machine & it worked well, So I guess there something else buggy in your code.

Comment: I am so sorry to bother you again,but can you give me all your test code?I just want to get an correct code...

Comment: you are so nice and cool.The problem is that in the Page_Load function I do not judge IsPostBack.Thank you very very very much!!