# OnCheckedChanged doesnt pick up function when checked

Tags: asp.net

Using a repeater, which displays a list, which includes a checkbox field.
When a checkbox is clicked I want the function to run and display the label....trying to debug this but cant seem to get it going, using breakpoint wont pick up the function

//code behind

```
 protected void chkMyCheck_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label.Text = "Button Clicked";
    }
```

aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptSelectedUtilities" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table class="detailstable FadeOutOnEdit">
                    <tr>   
                        <th style="width:200px;">Utility</th>    
                        <th style="width:200px;">Contacted</th>   
                        <th style="width:200px;">Comment</th>    
                    </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:200px;"><%# Eval("Name") %></th>
                        <th style="width:200px;"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkMyCheck" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkMyCheck_CheckedChanged" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Checked")) %>'/></th>   
                        <th style="width:200px;"><%# Eval("Comment") %></th>  
                    </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <asp:Label id="labelTableEmpty" runat="server" Text="There are currently no items in this table." />

        <asp:Label ID ="label" runat="server" />
```

Any idea as to why the code doesnt go into the chkMyCheck_CheckedChanged function when a checkbox is clicked?, the page does re-fresh so its picking up auto post back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you bind repeater inside of  !IsPostBack ????

for

```
void page_load()
{

if(!IsPostBack)
{
//BindRepeater method??? 
}
}
```

[Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590528/in-a-asprepeater-i-use-aspcheckbox-but-the-oncheckedchanged-doesnt-fire)